# Google Map Drag Concern

Tags: android, google-maps

I have following concern regarding `GoogleMap`:

When user drag map then after drag finish we hit web-service to get new set of results on map. Everything is working fine regardless of a wired thing, when user drag to new location then map goes to new location and we hit api for new location meanwhile map goes back to previous location and after getting results it comes back to new location.

**My concern is only: Map shouldn't go back to previous location if user dragged it. I want that it should stick to new location.**

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Without the code is difficult to help you.
I implemented some code that checks the new position after the drag (using the cameraChangeListener) and i have no problems about the position going back and forth. How do you handle that?